# AutoGenarate ID with a prefix in .net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My model is looks like this.

How could I autogenarate `ID` with a Prefix. Current scenario its gives only a number. I want to have a `ID` like `"GUID0001"`.

Can I do this within Model?

```
public class Link
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Shorted URL")]
    public string SURL { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("General Link")]
    public string OriginalURL { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Click Count")]
    public int ClickCount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you can use it in `Model` but you can achieve this in `view` using **[bindprefix](http://code.lawrab.com/2012/05/using-bind-prefix-in-aspnet-mvc.html)**

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate propery that looks like you want and do not store it in Data Base you can use [`NotMappedAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class Link
{
    /* Your properties */
    [NotMapped]
    public string IDWithPrefix { get { return "GUID" + ID.ToString(); } }
}
```

But you should understang that your `ID` now `Guid` type if you want `int` postfix after `"GUID"` `string` you must have `int` unique property in your model.